# jq command in windows not working as expected

Tags: windows, powershell, jq

I am trying to execute a simple jq command in windows but it is not working as expected

```
C:\Users\Administrator> aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids $instanceId --query "Reservations[0].Instances[0].Tags" | jq '.[] | select (.Key=="Name")'
```

Error:

```
jq: error: Name/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
.[] | select (.Key==Name)
jq: 1 compile error
```

Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Powershell, you have to backslash the double quotes for jq:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> '[{"name":"joe"}]' | jq '.[] | select (.name==\"joe\")'

{
  "name": "joe"
}
```